# USB keyboard stops responding randomly

Tags: usb, keyboard, hardware-failure

I am dual-booting relatively fresh Debian 12 install (6.1.0-16-amd64 kernel) and Windows 11 (***FAST BOOT IS TURNED OFF***).

My USB keyboard can stop responding at any moment. Sometimes there are troubles during boot (e.g. keyboard not working in GRUB menu or in BIOS), sometimes it can happen 30~50 minutes after boot. Other USB devices are working properly (see P.S), including a flash drive and wireless mouse (with a USB reciever).

First of all, I have tried googling. But to be precise, I have tried connecting this keyboard in all USB ports of my motherboard, tried removing all other devices (including mouse) and *tried using other keyboard*, no result. Also, I tried to set "usbcore.autosuspend=-1" and "usbcore.old_scheme_first=1" in my GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT setting in `/etc/default/grub` (I have ran `sudo update-grub` after this).

In Windows 11 there *are* some issues, but the keyboard does not turn off completely, instead, it can repeat single key until I unplug it from the PC. USB autosuspend (or whatever this setting is called in Windows) is disabled.

The issue *sometimes* can be **temporarily** fixed if I plug in the keyboard in another USB slot.

Example `dmesg --level=err` output:

```
[    9.745860] usb usb1-port6: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[  111.293266] usb usb1-port6: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[  547.208550] usb usb1-port6: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[  557.685632] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 5, error -71
[  567.953617] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 6, error -71
[  583.826059] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  599.441798] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  615.314514] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  631.138643] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  631.247839] usb usb1-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
[  730.752101] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 9, error -71
[  741.020226] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 10, error -71
[  756.884532] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  772.568763] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  788.373013] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  803.989229] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  804.098445] usb usb1-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
[  875.930235] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 13, error -71
[  886.406412] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 14, error -71
[  902.294724] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  931.758274] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[  960.475748] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[  985.643873] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[  991.691889] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[  992.154839] usb 5-1: can't set config #1, error -71
[  992.154939] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[  996.251936] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1025.052557] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1049.260758] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1050.300168] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1063.196207] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1097.996794] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1149.676616] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1177.212742] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1188.380858] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1190.925289] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1196.188833] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1209.613342] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1246.477095] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1247.549114] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1274.413199] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1359.165603] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1399.325788] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1403.981819] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1406.317822] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1467.550120] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1482.750197] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1548.414883] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1548.887619] usbhid 5-1:1.0: can't add hid device: -71
[ 1548.887785] usb usb5-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1553.736661] usb 5-1: device not accepting address 30, error -71
[ 1577.693109] usb usb3-port4: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1591.965210] usb usb3-port4: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1596.013230] usb usb3-port4: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1610.685312] usb usb3-port4: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1645.533452] usb usb3-port4: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1915.998732] usb usb3-port4: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 1952.510912] usb usb3-port4: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 2084.848063] usb usb3-port4: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 2197.088045] usb usb3-port4: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 2264.242157] usb usb3-port4: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
```

(full `dmesg` output: https://pastebin.com/EQLBQguN)

The error log states that there could be EMI, but the only things that are near my motherboard are PSU, HDD and SDD (I am running a system without a PC case).

Surely, that is a hardware-related issue. How do I debug it? Are both of my keyboards faulty?

P.S: While writing this, my mouse turned off once. It did not before.

Comment: If the problem happens at the same time that someone switches on a microwave oven, you might want to get that microwave oven replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this behaviour was motherboard's malfunction. I do not know what's the issue and whether this is a factory defect or not. I was using Gigabyte B450 S2H (Rev. 1.x) motherboard.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

The answer can be surmised from the question: "The error log states that **there could be EMI**, but the only things that are near my motherboard are PSU, HDD and SDD (I am running a system **without a PC case**)."

Consider the function of a case, aside from a place to rest your tea cup.